# Not retrieving data using Right Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

The Above screenshot is my table structure..

Invoice Table

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_TInvoice
(
InvoicePaymentId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PaymentDate DATE NOT NULL,
InvoicePaymentMethod VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,  
IsCashPayment BIT NOT NULL,
Note VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
IsRecordStatus BIT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(InvoicePaymentId)
)
```

Cash Inovice Table

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_TCashInvoice
(
CashInvoicePaymentId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
InvoicePaymentId BIGINT NOT NULL,
CashAmount  MONEY NULL,
CashReceived MONEY NULL,
CashBalance MONEY NULL,
IsRecordStatus BIT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(CashInvoicePaymentId)
)
```

I have used Right Join to retrieve data.

```
SELECT BASE_TInvoice.InvoicePaymentId, BASE_TInvoice.PaymentDate, BASE_TInvoice.InvoicePaymentMethod, BASE_TInvoice.IsCashPayment, BASE_TCashInvoice.CashAmount, BASE_TCashInvoice.CashReceived, BASE_TCashInvoice.CashBalance
FROM BASE_TCashInvoice RIGHT OUTER JOIN BASE_TInvoice ON BASE_TCashInvoice.InvoicePaymentId = BASE_TInvoice.InvoicePaymentId
WHERE (BASE_TInvoice.IsRecordStatus = 1) AND (BASE_TCashInvoice.IsRecordStatus IS NULL OR BASE_TCashInvoice.IsRecordStatus = 1) AND (BASE_TInvoice.InvoicePaymentId = 1)
```

The above query retrieving data fine, the bellow screenshot..
[image]

Once i set the BASE_TCashInvoice Status (IsRecordStatus) false and retrive data i'm getting blank, the below two screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I think the problem is in the where clause `(BASE_TCashInvoice.IsRecordStatus IS NULL OR BASE_TCashInvoice.IsRecordStatus = 1)`

How to retrieve exact data once BASE_TCashInvoice record InvoicePaymentId 1 and  IsRecordStatus went false need to display only the BASE_TInvoice table record only. Answer should be like below screenshot

[image]

Comment: And please next time, use text in your answer, not images. You can add an image and that's fine, for the tables' relationships. But for code and sample data, use text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem seems to be the condition that involves the `CashInvoice` table. 
It should be moved from `WHERE` to `ON`. Besides that, I'd make a few more changes to the query, to make it more readable:

- Refactor using aliases. Makes the queries shorter and easier to read.
- Add comments in your code.
- Format the queries nicely. No one likes to read code that is 300 characters wide.
- Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`. This is rather a stylistic matter but `RIGHT` joins are confusing to many. Even worse, if a query combines `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins. I suggest you use one or the other everywhere, with preference to `LEFT`. This way, the "base" table(s) can be put always first, after the `FROM` and the "optional" tables in the end. Makes it easier for the future reader to identify which is which, especially when the query has many joins.
- Add a statement terminator (`;`) at the end of every statement. Microsoft recommends that and in future versions non-terminated queries will be throwing errors (some already do).
- Adding the `WHERE` to `ON` move of the condition,

the query becomes:

```
SELECT 
    i  . InvoicePaymentId, 
    i  . PaymentDate, 
    i  . InvoicePaymentMethod, 
    i  . IsCashPayment, 
    ci . CashAmount, 
    ci . CashReceived, 
    ci . CashBalance
FROM
        BASE_TInvoice AS i              -- "base" table:      invoice:       i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        BASE_TCashInvoice AS ci         -- "optional" table:  cash invoice:  ci
    ON  
        ci.InvoicePaymentId = i.InvoicePaymentId 
        AND ( ci.IsRecordStatus IS NULL OR ci.IsRecordStatus = 1 ) 
WHERE 
      i.IsRecordStatus = 1  
  AND i.InvoicePaymentId = 1 ;
```

Comment: The above answer is correct 100%.  After On condition AND ( ci.IsRecordStatus IS NULL OR ci.IsRecordStatus = 1 ) i can use either (ci.IsRecordStatus = 1) only is that correct such as FROM BASE_TInvoice AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN BASE_TCashInvoice AS ci ON ci.InvoicePaymentId = i.InvoicePaymentId AND (ci.IsRecordStatus = 1 )  
 or this FROM BASE_TInvoice AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN BASE_TCashInvoice AS ci ON ci.InvoicePaymentId = i.InvoicePaymentId AND ( ci.IsRecordStatus IS NULL )

Comment: or i have to use both FROM BASE_TInvoice AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN BASE_TCashInvoice AS ci ON ci.InvoicePaymentId = i.InvoicePaymentId AND ( ci.IsRecordStatus IS NULL OR ci.IsRecordStatus = 1 )

Comment: In general, depends what you want as a result. But since (`ci.IsRecordStatus`) is not nullable, the `ci.IsRecordStatus IS NULL` can be omitted.